# Replacing a child instead of appending it to table

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, json

I have a button that adds rows to a table based on the data it gets from an array. However, I only want to append the first row and for the 2nd,3rd and so on it should replace the first row instead of appending it. I only want it to display one position at a time.

Another thing im struggling with:it displays the 2nd key in the object first instead of just displaying it how the array is structured. Why is that?

```js
var obj = {
  "15800175": {
    "posID": "159469",
    "scanID": "22597",
    "anr": "15800175",
    "TVanr": "",
    "code": "G-09-27-2E",
    "ean": "4710069680575",
    "marke": "fox",
    "bez": "jersey yellow",
    "bez2": "size xl",
    "menge": "1",
    "ve": "St\u00fcck",
    "Dimensionstext": "TT9857BG\r\n",
    "Langtext": ""
  },
  "15100027": {
    "posID": "159471",
    "scanID": "22597",
    "anr": "15100027",
    "TVanr": "",
    "code": "G-11-03-2A",
    "ean": "4712511825411",
    "marke": "fox",
    "bez2": "jersey L",
    "menge": "1",
    "ve": "St\u00fcck",
    "Dimensionstext": "blue\r\n",
    "Langtext": ""
  }
}
var counter = 0;
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
document.getElementById("btnAdd").onclick = function(event) {
  //variables
  let tbody = document.getElementById("tbodyExample");

  //logic
  let element = arr[counter] != undefined ? arr[counter] : undefined;
  if (element !== undefined) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr'); //'<tr id="'+element.posID+'">       </tr>';
    row.setAttribute("id", element.posID);
    row.innerHTML = '<td>' + element.posID + '</td><td>' + element.code + '</td>  <td>' + (element.bez == undefined ? element.bez2 : element.bez) + '</td><td>' + element.anr + '</td><td>' + element.menge + '</td><td>' + element.ve + '</td>';
    tbody.appendChild(row);
    counter++;
  } else {
    alert("No more items found");
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btnAdd">Add</button>
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody id="tbodyExample"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: First thing if you're writing code please use proper indent it will help you learn. It will also help if someone will need to read your code (or you if you will check your code week later after you wrote it) check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style

Comment: I edited it now, sorry!

Comment: _I only want to append the first row and for the 2nd,3rd and so on it should replace_ You want to replace the table row or the values of the table row? Why there's a button for adding rows if you're using only one line?

Comment: _“Another thing im struggling with:it displays the 2nd key in the object first instead of just displaying it how the array is structured. Why is that?”_ - because objects don’t guarantee property order*. If you log `obj` to console, you will see `15100027` show up first and `15800175` second there already. (* not actually generally true, see https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/ - but it is the explanation for what you are seeing here.)

Comment: I made you a snippet. Much easier to discuss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object is created in integer order - if you do not want that, you need to make the key not a number like I now did

You can use the [deleteRow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/deleteRow) method

Note I test if one exists and I do not delete the last one if there are none left

I also added a search and refactored the disabling of the buttons into a function of its own

```js
var JSONString = `{ "15800175": { "posID": "159469", "scanID": "22597", "anr": "15800175", "TVanr": "", "code": "G-09-27-2E", "ean": "4710069680575", "marke": "fox", "bez": "jersey yellow", "bez2": "size xl", "menge": "1", "ve": "St\u00fcck", "Dimensionstext": "TT9857BG\\r\\n", "Langtext": "" }, "15100027": { "posID": "159471", "scanID": "22597", "anr": "15100027", "TVanr": "", "code": "G-11-03-2A", "ean": "4712511825411", "marke": "fox", "bez2": "jersey L", "menge": "1", "ve": "St\u00fcck", "Dimensionstext": "blue\\r\\n", "Langtext": "" } }` 

JSONString = JSONString.replace(/"(\d+)":/g, '"_$1":')
var obj = JSON.parse(JSONString);
console.log(Object.keys(obj))

let counter = -1;
const arr = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
const tbody = document.getElementById("tbodyExample");

function showElement(counter,dir) {

  if (dir !=null && (counter === -1 || counter >= arr.length)) {
    counter = dir === 1 ? arr.length - 1 : 0;
  }

  document.getElementById("prev").disabled = counter <= 0;
  document.getElementById("next").disabled = counter === arr.length - 1;

  let element = arr[counter];

  var row = document.createElement('tr'); //'<tr id="'+element.posID+'">       </tr>';
  row.setAttribute("id", element.posID);
  row.innerHTML = '<td>' + element.posID + '</td><td>' + element.code + '</td>  <td>' + (element.bez ? element.bez : element.bez2) + '</td><td>' + element.anr + '</td><td>' + element.menge + '</td><td>' + element.ve + '</td>';

  let firstRow = tbody.querySelector("tr");
  if (firstRow) tbody.deleteRow(0);
  tbody.appendChild(row);
  document.getElementById("barcode").value=element.anr;
}

document.getElementById("navigation").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const tgt = event.target;
  if (tgt.className !== "nav") return;
  const dir = tgt.id === "prev" ? -1 : 1;
  counter += dir;
  showElement(counter,dir)
});
document.getElementById("next").click()

document.getElementById("barcode").addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
    var anr = this.value.trim();
    var index = arr.findIndex(x => x.anr === anr);
    if (index != -1) showElement(index)
    else {
      console.log(anr, "not found");
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="barcode" placeholder="Barcode" value="" />
<div id="navigation"><button type="button" id="prev" class="nav">Prev</button><button type="button" id="next" class="nav">Next</button></div>
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody id="tbodyExample"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199002/discussion-on-answer-by-mplungjan-replacing-a-child-instead-of-appending-it-to-t).

Comment: Just a quick follow up question, with the current code,  `if (counter === arr.length) { alert("done";}` is not working anymore. It gives me  `ReferenceError: dir is not defined` could you help me out with that, please?

Comment: Ah, oops - I’ll look

Comment: Can't seem to figure out what the issue is :/

Comment: I’ll look when I have some time

Comment: I think I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [deleteRow()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_deleterow.asp) method

```
var obj = {
  "15800175": {
    "posID": "159469",
    "scanID": "22597",
    "anr": "15800175",
    "TVanr": "",
    "code": "G-09-27-2E",
    "ean": "4710069680575",
    "marke": "fox",
    "bez": "jersey yellow",
    "bez2": "size xl",
    "menge": "1",
    "ve": "St\u00fcck",
    "Dimensionstext": "TT9857BG\r\n",
    "Langtext": ""
  },
  "15100027": {
    "posID": "159471",
    "scanID": "22597",
    "anr": "15100027",
    "TVanr": "",
    "code": "G-11-03-2A",
    "ean": "4712511825411",
    "marke": "fox",
    "bez2": "jersey L",
    "menge": "1",
    "ve": "St\u00fcck",
    "Dimensionstext": "blue\r\n",
    "Langtext": ""
  }
}
var counter = 0;
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
document.getElementById("btnAdd").onclick = function(event) {
  //variables
  let tbody = document.getElementById("tbodyExample");

  //logic

  // clear the first row
  document.getElementById("yourTableId").deleteRow(0);

  let element = arr[counter] != undefined ? arr[counter] : undefined;
  if (element !== undefined) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr'); //'<tr id="'+element.posID+'">       </tr>';
    row.setAttribute("id", element.posID);
    row.innerHTML = '<td>' + element.posID + '</td><td>' + element.code + '</td>  <td>' + (element.bez == undefined ? element.bez2 : element.bez) + '</td><td>' + element.anr + '</td><td>' + element.menge + '</td><td>' + element.ve + '</td>';
    tbody.appendChild(row);
    counter++;
  } else {
    alert("No more items found");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note that this code actually does not work if there are no rows in the table